# Column Name and Value of second highest values

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify for each row the column names with the highest and second highest values if they have a value not equal to zero in the row. Dataset:

```
DT=data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5),Price=c(2.1,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.5),
      '2.0'= c(100,300,700,400,0),
      '2.1'= c(400,200,100,500,0),
      '2.2'= c(600,700,200,100,-200),
      '2.3'= c(300,0,-300,100,100),
      '2.4'= c(400,0,0,500,600),
      '2.5'= c(0,200,0,800,-100),check.names=FALSE)
```

The objective is the have the highest column value that has any value not equal to zero in it in the Highest column, and the column with the second highest value that has any value not equal to zero in it in the Second column:

```
DT=data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5),Price=c(2.1,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.5),
      '2.0'= c(100,300,700,400,0),
      '2.1'= c(400,200,100,500,0),
      '2.2'= c(600,700,200,100,-200),
      '2.3'= c(300,0,-300,100,100),
      '2.4'= c(400,0,0,500,600),
      '2.5'= c(0,200,0,800,-100),check.names=FALSE,
      Highest=c(2.4,2.5,2.3,2.5,2.5),Second=c(2.3,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4))
```

The code for Highest is:

```
DT$Highest <- apply(DT[-1], 1, function(x) max(as.numeric(names(which(x>0|x<0)))))
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
DT$highest = colnames(DT)[2+apply(DT[,3:8], 1, function(x)
                   which(x != 0 & x == sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1])[1])]
#[1] "2.2" "2.2" "2.0" "2.5" "2.4"  

DT$second_highest = colnames(DT)[2+apply(DT[,3:8], 1, function(x)
                   which(x != 0 & x == sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2])[1])]
#[1] "2.1" "2.0" "2.2" "2.1" "2.3"
```